# My angular 7 app is not able to load chunks from proper folder

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, angular7, chunks

I have an ASP.NET MVC application, with front-end is angular-cli (angular 7).
Ever since upgrading from 6 to 7 the paths of the chunks are wrong. Apparently the angular is trying to load chunks(using lazy loading) from the root(/) while it is generated in the dist folder. So it gives me 404 error, although the chunks are there in the dist folder

I have tried using ng build --prod --base-href dist
Also tried changing baseUrl in my ts.config.
Probably there should be some option in angular.json to change this behavior.

here is my angular.json

````
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "testapp": {
      "root": "dist/",
      "sourceRoot": "NgSrc",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "build": 
        {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "NgSrc/index.html",
            "main": "NgSrc/App/main.ts",
            "tsConfig": "NgSrc/tsconfig.app.json",
            "polyfills": "NgSrc/polyfills.ts",
            "assets": [
              "NgSrc/assets",
              "NgSrc/favicon.ico"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/angular2-toaster/toaster.min.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
              // "node_modules/angular2-toastr/bundles/angular2-toaster.umd.min.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "NgSrc/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "NgSrc/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "testapp:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "testapp:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "testapp:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "NgSrc/test.ts",
            "karmaConfig": "./karma.conf.js",
            "polyfills": "NgSrc/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "NgSrc/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
              "node_modules/ng2-toastr/bundles/ng2-toastr.min.js"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/ng2-toastr/bundles/ng2-toastr.min.css"
            ],
            "assets": [
              "NgSrc/assets",
              "NgSrc/favicon.ico"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "testapp-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e",
      "sourceRoot": "e2e",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "./protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "testapp:serve"
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "testapp",
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "prefix": "app",
      "styleext": "css"
    },
    "@schematics/angular:directive": {
      "prefix": "app"
    }
  }
}```
````

Answer (score 3):

For those who are clueless like me, The answer lies in the angular.json configuration file. Apparently, there are 2 properties **baseHref** & **deployUrl** that we need to understand. **baseHref** defines the base URL for the application and **deployUrl** is URL where files will be deployed. So in order to load chunks from a separate folder, we will need to modify deployUrl.

```
"architect": {
    "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "options": {
        "baseHref": "/dist/", 
        "deployUrl": "/dist/",            
        "outputPath": "../dist"
        ...
       }
     }
 }
```